# In what order would the dynamical added script files be executed in this case?

Tags: javascript

I read an article here:

https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html

It says that I should use something like this to load javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
  var element = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "defer.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

I am wondering, if I have more than one `defer.js` to load, in what order would it be executed?

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
  var element1 = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "defer1.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  var element2 = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "defer2.js";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Will the `defer1.js` SURELY be executed before `defer2.js`?

Thanks

Comment: The article claims that this is better than simply putting the script tags at the end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. I beg to differ. That's been working beautifully for millions of websites for well over a decade.

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild()`synchronously appends the script node, but it loads the script asynchronously. So the execution order is undefined (it depends on network delays).

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering, if I have more than one defer.js to load, in what order would it be executed?

Chaotically.

> Will the `defer1.js` SURELY be executed before `defer2.js`?

No.

When you add scripts dynamically like that, there is no guarantee about the order. They'll be run as soon as they're retrieved, and so if `defer2.js` is retrieved more quickly than `defer1.js`, it'll run first.

To do them in order, you'd have to request them in order, which means you can't request `defer2.js` until you've received a `load` event on `defer1.js`. Which means you'll download your JavaScript more slowly, because the browser can't make the requests in parallel, which it can do if you just put the script tags at the end of the document just prior to the closing `</body>` tag.

---

You've said you're concerned about getting a less-than-perfect score from PageSpeed Insights. Don't worry. Despite what your linked article says, PageSpeed Insights is plenty smart enough to know that `script` tags immediately prior to the closing `</body>` tag do not pose any load-time problem. This page, for instance, receives 100/100 on PageSpeed Insights if you serve the JavaScript with proper caching headers:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Testing</title>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Testing 1 2 3.</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(Where `script1.js` and `script2.js` have a bit of jQuery code in them.)

Of course, where possible, avoid having multiple scripts (e.g., combine `script1.js` and `script2.js` above if you can; there are arguments either way about whether to include jQuery in that one combined file or use a CDN as above).

Comment: But if I put it right before the `</body>` tag, the Google Speed Insight wouldn't give me a full score. How could I do that in a perfect solution?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: Have you checked that that's actually true? Because I just tested it and got 100/100 (for desktop, my test page didn't cater to mobile). Unsurprisingly, PageSpeed Insight is smart enough to understand that `script` tags immediately prior to the closing `</body>` tag *don't* impact your load performance.

Comment: You mean as long as I put the script tag right before the `</body>` and I'm saved? Would you mind sending me your page if it's not private? Thanks!

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo: Yes, that's right. I've added an example above that gets 100/100 from PageSpeed Insights (both desktop and mobile).

Answer (score 0):

defer1.js this script will load first and then 
defer2.js thi one load and so on